# cerberus: forbid field existance

Tags: python, validation, cerberus

I want to use Cerberus to validate that a field is **NOT** present in the object.

I would like to use something like:

```
my_schema = {
    'normal_field': {
        'type': 'string',
    },
    'forbidden_field': {
        'forbid': True,
    },
}
```

Basically, I would like to never accept an object that comes with the `forbidden_field`. Right now I am accepting changing my validator with:

```
validator.allow_unknown = False
```

Which basically does the trick on setting a schema with only "allowed" fields, but I don't really like what it does, as this forbids me to accept other fields, not only the `forbidden_field`.

I also saw the `allowed` and `forbidden` validation rules, but they check the value of the field, not really the existence of the field.

So, how could I tell my validator to only forbid specific field existence with Cerberus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem with the [`readonly`](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#readonly) rule which also allowed me to set a `default_setter` value.

@kchan's answer works for not allowing the field, but it breaks normalization integration (trying to use it with `default_setter` for example).

Answer (score 2):

I seem to recall encountering this particular use case before. You might try the following:

```
from cerberus import Validator

schema = {
    'foo': {
        'type': 'string',
        'validator': lambda field, value, error: error(field, 'field is forbidden!!'),
    }
}
v = Validator(schema)
v.allow_unknown = True
doc = {
    'foo': 'bar'
}
print(v.validate(doc))
```

The result should return `False` and `v.errors` should say "field is forbidden!!"

see:

- [`validator` under Validation Rules in the Cerberus documentation](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html)